# How to get fmt::Display from a struct to display it in the fmt::Display of another struct?

Tags: struct, rust

Im not sure how to name this question as I am new to Rust so feel free to suggest edits.

I have two structs. One is a `Job` struct, which contains a few numbers like how long a job takes, etc.
The other is a `JobSequence`, which contains a `Vec()` of `Job`s.

I implemented the `fmt::Display` trait for the `Job` so that it prints out its three number in this way:

```
(10, 12, 43)
```

Now, I would like to implement the `fmt::Display` trait for the `JobSequence` struct so that it iterates over each `Job` in the vector and displays them in this way:

```
(0, 10, 5)
(30, 10, 5)
(0, 10, 5)
(0, 10, 5)
(0, 10, 5)
```

I think(?) I should reuse the implemented trait of the `Job` struct and use it so that it simply, in a way, printouts them as a semi-list. This is my current implementation, but i have a feeling that is sloppy and there is a better way:

```rust
pub struct JobSequence {
    pub job_sequence: Vec<Job>,
}

impl fmt::Display for JobSequence {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        let mut final_output = String::new();
        for i in &self.job_sequence {
            final_output.push_str(i.to_string().as_str());
            final_output.push_str("\n");
        }
        write!(f, "{}", final_output)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can re-use the the `Display` impl by passing it directly to `write!` with the `{}` format string:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for JobSequence {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        for i in &self.job_sequence {
            writeln!(f, "{}", i)?;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

You can read more about the different traits used by the formatting macros in [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html#formatting-traits). (A plain `{}` uses `std::fmt::Display`.)

Comment: I undersand that the Ok(()) is needed so simply know that everything went right, so is it the writeln! macro that actually does the thing? Im confused

Comment: Yes, the `writeln!` line will write `i` to `f` using the `std::fmt::Display` impl of `i`, followed by a newline (`write!` will do the same except the newline).